# maven doesnt seem to be installing with springsource tool suite

Tags: spring, maven, command-line, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I recently installed the springsource tool suite plugin for eclipse, running on windows 7.  But when I open a command prompt (by typing cmd in the windows start menu) and type in:

```
mvn --version
```

I get the following response:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
```

So I then downloaded the stand-alone version of springsource tool suite, which is not what I want.  And nonetheless, I still get the same response on the command line when I type in mvn --version.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

I get the same response when I type in java -version .  So this might be a command prompt problem.  I a following the exact syntax from web tutorials.

EDIT:
I just tried to download m2e in the eclipse marketplace, but got the message that there is nothing new to install.  This seems to indicate that I have maven installed, so then how do I access it via the command line in windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [configure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm) your Maven environment variable to be able to use it in the command prompt.

In your case there's no need to download the maven binars because it comes with STS, just find the Maven folder inside the STS directory.

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for trying to help.  I looked in the plugins folder of my eclipse installation, and found 19 jar files for m2e.  To which of them should I point?  And what should I point there?  Am I creating windows environment variables?  Can you be more explicit?  Please not that java -version also produces the same error at the command prompt, even though java is clearly installed and working.  I just noticed that the cmd.exe instance I am using is in the sytem32 folder, while these programs might be 64 bit.  How would I accommodate that?

Comment: What you have to keep in mind is that you have to configured them as windows environment variables in order to make them work in your command prompt. You are thinking about maven as a plugin only, when you use the STS you already have the maven plugin installed, it's used to build your projects inside the STS, not to use it in command line. To to that you have to point the folder inside your STS installation (Something like: 64bits ~> C:\Program Files\STS\apache-maven3.x and 32bits ~> C:\Program Files (x86)\STS\apache-maven3.x)

Comment: If you don't find this folder you can download the maven, put it wherever you want and point to its installation folder in your environment variable. Link: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: if none of this helps you, you can go with this step-by-step from the mkyong's blog: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

"___" is not recognized as an internal or external command
is shown when program is not installed or the path of that program is not set (to execute from other path).

remember, in "STS", maven is not configured to work out of STS (and terminal usage is out of STS usage).
we have to install it.
maven download link is here
[download latest maven from here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

extract it where ever you want.
i extracted as below (see the bin,boot,conf,... folders are shown below as in the image):
[image]

**as this maven download is extracted from zip file (it is not setup), you will have to add this extracted path to "PATH" variable in windows environment.
follow this to set environment path:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

now "mvn" command must work.
**but**
**in my case i had to restart STS (spring tool suit) for this to work**