# Where is the settings.xml used by maven in the Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'd like to set the ftp servers for deploying from STS as described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html

It should be in the settings.xml.
According to documentation settings is in either of 2:

- The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
- A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

Where is the $M2_HOME. In other terms when working from STS(Eclipse), what is the installation folder for maven in this case. I can't find a settings.xml in ${user.home}/.m2/ .
I worked under Windows 7

Those 2 threads are related but do not provide a clear answer that worked for me at least:

- [maven doesnt seem to be installing with springsource tool suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454648/maven-doesnt-seem-to-be-installing-with-springsource-tool-suite)
- [Eclipse (STS) + Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341004/eclipse-sts-maven) , I have nothing appearing in the screenshot suggested in this last thread.

Thx in advance

Comment: I believe I had to set the $M2_HOME as a "Linked Resource" in Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Linked Resource.  However, the ${user.home} should work as-is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I may be off-mark as I've never used STS myself, but if I understand correctly it is just a pre-packaged Eclipse distribution. If I'm correct your installation only contains an embedded version of Maven, but not a command line accessible one. You need to install one from [here](http://maven.apache.org/).

With the 3.x releases of Eclipse I found that you need to have your installation point to an external Maven installation for Eclipse to make use of the `settings.xml` files. Once you installed a downloaded version you can choose `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations`, press `Add...` and point to the version you just installed.

Comment: I did not install any version it comes built-in with STS.

Comment: That's my point. The build in version can only be used from within Eclipse, but not from the command line. Even the Maven related `Run as...` commands should not run in your installation. If I were you I'd also install a free-standing Maven and have Eclipse point to it.

Answer (score 7):

In Spring Tools Suite (3.6.1):

Windows - Preferences - Maven - User Settings, you can select which global- and user- version of the settings.xml to use.

Answer (score 4):

Global maven settings.xml exist at `apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml` [inside the maven installation]

and

Local maven settings.xml exist at `C\Users\[username]\.m2\settings.xml`[window OS install on C drive]

Comment: The question I am asking is where is the apache-maven-3.0.4 when working in STS

Comment: parallel folder of STS